# How long can a binary string be when converting? (Python)

Tags: python, binary, integer, byte, radix

Knowing the following:

> sys.getsizeof(int())
>
> 24 (number of bytes?)
>
> int('11111111', 2)
>
> 255

How long can the binary string be?

example this works as well:

> int('1111111111111111', 2)
>
> 65535

So how long can my length of my binary string be maximum?!

Comment: You should do some testing on this and tell us the answer.

Comment: Klaus D. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can make it as long as you want (of course depending on your RAM), because both ints and strings can have any length in Python.